# jquery validate show error on dynamic field name

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using the jquery validate plugin to validate my form. There is also server side validation and I'd like to be able to flag up the fields showing errors from the server side validation such as unique email if it's not been caught by the jquery validation.

I'm receiving a json object from my server script which has field name and then error.

I thought of using the `showErrors()` function but can't work out the right way to get this to work. Here's my script so far:

```
$.each(errors, function (key, value) {
    console.log("Key:", key);
    validator.showErrors({
    key: value[0]
    })
});
```

This throws an error - `uncaught typeError` so I assume referencing key as the field name doesn't cut it. I realise it's evaluating `key` as the field name rather than the value contained in `key` which is what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looping through a JSON object.
I will assume that your `errors` json object it is something like this:

```
var errors = [
  {"firstname": "I know that your firstname is Ray, Ray!"},
  {"age":"You're not so old"},
  {"job":"You're not Buddha"}
];
```

At the first iteration of your `$.each` loop the `v` parameter it's the whole object at `k` position, in this case:

```
{"firstname": "I know that your firstname is Pete, Pete!"}
```

You can see that here is needed a second `$.each` loop that will iterates over the properties on each object element.

```
$.each(errors, function() {
  $.each(this, function(k, v) {
    /* ... code ... */
  });
});
```

From [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.showErrors/) `showErrors` methods take an `Object` as a parameter.
You need to build it.

```
//my validator object
var validator = $( "#yourFormID" ).validate();

// empty object that I'll fill with name input/errors
var objErrors = {};

//iterate over array of objects/maps
$.each(errors, function() {
  //iterate over the properties on each object
  $.each(this, function(k, v) {
    objErrors[k] = v;
  });
});
validator.showErrors(objErrors);
```

In the loops I've built my object that I've passed to the method `showErrors` of the object `validator`.
I choose this solution because like so, I call only one time `showErrors` instead of calling it everytime in the `$.each` loop.

[Here](https://jsbin.com/puxotobuwi/edit?html,js,output) a working jsbin example.

Comment: That's great. I'll have a go at implementing tonight. Thank you for a through answer. Really useful. Thank you